# HTML/CSS Positioning confusion

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've been looking everywhere and I took a course on codecademy but I still cannot do it on my own work. The problem is I understand it when I'm reading about it etc but simply cannot use it or figure out how to do it when I'm doing my own website.

How exactly do I position something to where I want it to be? What should I look for? There's like 100 ways to edit positioning and it confuses me a lot..

I would appreciate some pointers in how to know what to use when positioning. I have the idea of the website but positioning all of this is very tough. I want to use images in the future for all of this too but I'm just trying to do this with html/css no images first. I think I'm more of a designer but I really wish I knew this so I can do it properly from now on.

My direct question is how would I move  to the position of middle of the page, near the end of

My CSS code right now is as follows

```
         body
            {
                margin: 0;
                background: #838383;
                font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
            }
        header
            {
                height: 200px;
                background: #222;
                color: white;

            }

        nav
            {
                width: 500px;
            }

        nav ul
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: ;
            }
        nav ul li
            {
                color: white;
                display: inline;
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 5px 15px;
            }
        nav ul li a
            {
                color: white;
            }

        .login
            {
                margin: 300px;
                text-align: center;

            }

        .login p
            {

            }
```

HTML code

```
             <html>
                <head> 
                    <title> Login </title> 
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <header>
                        <nav >
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                        <div class="login">
                            <h1>Login</h1>
                                <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username"></p>
                                <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                                <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                <footer></footer>

              </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: _"how would I move to the position of middle of the page, near the end of"_ I don't understand what you are asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: This question is difficult to read or comprehend with the incomplete sentences and missing subjects. From what I can glean, though, it sounds like what you want is a tutorial on CSS positioning. To that, I say there are thousands upon thousands of them online. Just look them up.

Comment: @Jack Sorry I didn't see I didn't complete the sentence. I'm trying to move the nav element to the middle of the screen (the links) and then down. So I suppose I would need to edit the margin/padding but that also moves everything else.

Comment: @Jack I'm trying to move it down to the bottom of the dark header. Not below it, but just at the bottom of it, still inside the dark area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are wanting to do?:

http://jsfiddle.net/8y00nhnc/

Here are my changes:

```
    nav
        {
            width: 500px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

    nav ul
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Yes! I also used padding-top to move it down. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posted an answer below based on your updated comments. I think it's more of what you're looking for. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the login section inside the black header area you need to do:

First move the login div inside the nav div:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username"></p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

Then change the nav's width to 100%:

```
 nav {
    width: 100%;
     }
```

Lastly use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the login div and give it some padding for styling:

```
.login {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1bhfm0bo/2/

Comment: I was looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/1bhfm0bo/3/

Only problem now I have is I don't really know how to vertically align the whole login class without manually guessing with margin-top

(I have a feeling I'm doing this very inefficiently :/ and there's a lot easier way)

Comment: Oh, okay. Your question was unclear. Glad you solved it.

Comment: @Xylus sometimes manually guessing is what it takes until it looks right. Try using a %age instead of a px value if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to position first of all? It looks like the login since you have so much margin on it. This will float your login in the middle of the page. Will only work on modern browsers. Change your HTML to as follows:

HTML

```
<body>
   <header>
      <nav >
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="login">
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <p><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username"></p>
          <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
          <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
   position: relative;
}

.login {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* add vender prefixes */
}
```